# Is it possible to change the license violation settings in Artifactory pro/Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I've been working with Artifactory pro and Jenkins (using the Jenkins plugin) and I've been trying to configure my build to report on license violations with other types of statuses, i.e. statuses other than unknown or unapproved.

[The JFrog license control documentation states](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/License+Control):

> "You can also set a list of recipients to be notified about license violations as soon as they occur.  This way whenever a dependency with an unknown or unapproved license is added to the build recipients receive an immediate email notification and can tend to any potential license violation."

Inside Artifactory there are a few more settings, these are:

- Unknown
- Unapproved
- Not Found
- Neutral
- Approved

[This corresponds to the REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-LicenseSearch):

> Usage: GET /api/search/license[?unapproved=1][&unknown=1][&notfound=0][&neutral=0][&approved=0][&autofind=0][&repos=x[,y]]

Unfortunately, I don't see a way to change these settings in Artifactory directly, and there's no REST API call that I can find which allows me to set these values.

Is there any way to set these values (either in the Artifactory server or the Jenkins plugin) to return 'Neutral' as a license violation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make sense of those statuses first.
For each and every license, there are only two statuses: Approved or not (it's a checkbox, true or false).

Out of this simple boolean value, Artifactory calculate a state of an artifact:

- Unknown - the found license doesn't match any of license types known to Artifactory
- Unapproved - we found one or more licenses, all of them are of unapproved type
- Not Found - there is no information about the license in pom.xml (ivy.xml)
- Neutral - we found multiple licenses, some of them are approved, others are not
- Approved - we found one or more licenses, all of them are of approved type

Currently the list of triggers for the email notification is hard-coded to Unknown and Unproved. You're more than welcome to [open a feature request](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/HAP) to make it customizable (I can imagine a list of checkboxes for selecting/deselecting every one of the states)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since it's hard-coded I'll reconsider whether I truly need the email notification.

Comment: Feature request won't hurt, will it? Go figure, you might write now something ad-hoc and use the REST-API and switch to the email notification once the request is completed.

Comment: No, I feature request wont hurt. I will be making the request once I know from the product owner whether the email notification was necessary or a nice-to-have.

I've looked into the REST API and have considered a short term solution. Should be easy enough given the license search call.